# How get value from json_encoded formate using PHP?

Tags: php

In the MySQL table, I have 3 column which is **tour_from**, **tour_to**, and **pickup**.

I have saved these value as **json_encode** formate.

**tour_from**

```
[["one","three","five"],["seven","nine","eleven"],["thirteen","fifteen","seventeen"]]
```

**tour_to**

```
[["two","four","six"],["eight","ten","twelve"],["fourteen","sixten","eighteen"]]
```

**pickup**

```
[["01:00","01:00","01:00"],["01:00","01:00","01:00"],["01:00","01:00","01:00"]]
```

Now I want to output the these as below:

```
one        two       01:00
thre       four      01:00
five       six       01:00
seven      eight     01:00
nine       ten       01:00
eleven     twelve    01:00
thirteen   fourteen  01:00
fifteen    sixteen   01:00
seventeen  eighteen  01:00
```

I can output the **tour_from** value but can't output the other 2 column value

```
$from             =  json_decode($data['tour_from'], true);
$to               =  json_decode($data['tour_to'], true);
$pickup           =  json_decode($data['pickup'], true);

foreach ($from[$gKey] as $key1 => $value1) {

$html .=<<<EOD
    <tr>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>$value1</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>$to[$gKey][$key1]</td>
        <td>Pickup</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

EOD;    
}
```

My head is going to break but can't find the way :(

Visual Output:

[image]

Comment: Where is the $data array being formed (that you're using json_decode on)?

Comment: Have you tried *helping* PHP to decide where variable ends with `{$to[$gKey][$key1]}`

Comment: maybe cut down on useless complexity ...

Comment: Not sure how you create those 3 JSON's but I am sure there must be a better way

Comment: @Justinas I have used but ti's showing me this error:  Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\freelancer\job\process\download.php on line 17

Comment: @MartinZeitler may be you are right :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, may be :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly caching responses which won't change much in the file-system would probably make more sense, than to request them from a database, in order to `json_decode()` them.

Comment: I have live url if you want then I can share with you.

Comment: think about restructuring how you safe your data...

Comment: Strange!!!!!: Using `var_dump($to[$gKey][$key1]);` it's showing D:\xampp\htdocs\.....\download.php:175:string 'two' (length=3)

Comment: but when I use $to[$gKey][$key1] it's showing array to string conversation error message :( :( :(

Comment: @TarasV I don't understand.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/RunnyPlumpCallback

Comment: @TarasV Yes, it's showing output.